# Create a presence-absence matrix with presence on specific dates

Tags: r, matrix, behavior, data-wrangling

I want to create a presence/absence matrix that has the date on the y-axes and individuals on the x-axes. When an individual was present on the particular date, the output should be 1, while if it was absent the output should be 0.
I have a dataframe with the names of individuals and the dates that they are present in a group:

| ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afr | 2015-06-29 | 2016-02-16 |
| Ahe | 2016-12-18 | 2018-02-24 |
| Art | 2015-07-01 | 2020-04-30 |
| ... |  |  |

In total I have over a thousand individuals and their dates.

I also have a list/dataframe that contains all the dates from 2015-01-01 to 2021-31-12.

My output data needs to look like this:

| Date | Afr | Ahe | Art | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-07-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 2015-07-02 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 2015-07-03 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Where the output is 1 when an individual was present in the group at that time and a 0 when it was not.
I feel like there should be an easy solution for creating this but so far I have not managed. One of the problems I am encountering is that the list of dates is for example longer than the dataframe with the individuals, making a `dcast` function for example impossible.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Please also let me know if I should provide more code/background.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the code below

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

na.omit(
  dcast(
    df1[df2, .(Date, ID), on = .(Start < Date, End > Date)][df1, on = .(ID)],
    Date ~ ID,
    fun.aggregate = length
  )
)
```

which gives

```
         Date Afr Ahe Art
1: 2015-07-01   1   0   0
2: 2015-07-02   1   0   1
3: 2015-07-03   1   0   1
```

## Data

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(ID = c("Afr", "Ahe", "Art"), Start = structure(c(16615, 
17153, 16617), class = "Date"), End = structure(c(16847, 17586,
18382), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16617, 16618, 16619), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```